# Find the corners of a rectangle plate in a picture

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, corner-detection

I need to find the coordinates of the corners of a rectangle plate in a picture, using Python and OpenCv.

This is what the original picture looks like:

[image: Original picture of the plate]
Now I use the following script for edge detection:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_original = cv2.imread('c:/python_test/camera_pics/Basler_acA640-300gm__22354308__20210211_135725420_36.tiff', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
filtered_image = cv2.Canny(image_gray, threshold1=20, threshold2=200)

cv2.imwrite('c:/python_test/test.bmp',filtered_image)
```

And then it looks like this:

[image: Picture after edge detection]

Now I am trying to find the corners of the plate, but I have no idea how I can do this. These corners can either be the corners of the inner rectangle or the outer rectangle. I edited the picture below in Paint to show which corners I mean.

[image: I edited the picture in Paint to show which corners I mean]

Can you help me in writing a script to find the coordinates of the corners of this plate?

Comment: The last image which corners detected is the desired image you wanna ? How did you draw those circles ?

Comment: The desired image I want to have does not have to look like this with the drawings on it. I only want to have the coordinates of the corners stored in a variable.

I made this image in Paint to show which corners I mean.

Comment: I think the upper-outer-corners could be found by computing the convex hull around all edge pixels. Same would work with the lower-outer-corners if the object was thin. The inner corners will be even more difficult to extract. Mayb try EDLines or LSD whether they give better edge results for that task.

Comment: are you allowed to modify the plate in any way? Stick markers on the corners or something to make it easier to detect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an uneasy task, especially for the two lower corners of the upper face. Contrast is low (even inexistent at places) and the image is cluttered.

The convex hull will indeed give you the two top corners (provided the screws are always detectable). You can also find the bottom corners of the lower face by finding significant angles in the convex hull.

You can somewhat approximate the locations of the corners of the upper face knowing the thickness of the plate and its projected height compared to true height.

As the long edges are not so badly detected, you may consider the long, continuous line segments (in the 8-connectedness sense), and try to match them to the convex hull and to the estimated corners.